# node.js Nerve framework unicode response

Tags: unicode, utf-8, node.js

code:

```
var nerve = require("./nerve");
var sitemap = [
    ["/", function(req, res) {
        res.respond("Русский");
    }]
];
nerve.create(sitemap).listen(8100);
```

show in browser:

```
CAA:89
```

How it should be correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nerve [appears](http://github.com/gjritter/nerve/blob/master/lib/nerve.js#L27) to interpret the strings you pass as binary strings, which results in the output you’re seeing. You can use the Buffer class to convert your UTF-8 chars to a binary string manually. You also need to set the charset in your headers:

```
var sitemap = [
  ["/", function (req, res) {
    res.respond({
      headers: {"Content-Type": "text/html; charset=utf-8"},
      content: new Buffer("Русский", "utf8").toString("binary")
    });
  }]
];
```

If you want to try another framework, [Express](http://expressjs.com) does a better job handling UTF-8. It interprets strings as UTF-8 and sets the charset correctly by default:

```
var app = require("express").createServer();

app.get("/", function (req, res) {
  res.send("Русский");
});

app.listen(8100);
```

Comment: Oh dear. And from that git link, Nerve also seems to have an HTML-injection vuln in the error page. Whoops. Not very good.