# What is wrong with node js dealing with cyrillic encoding

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, utf-8, character-encoding

If you take the very basic, very simple example from the

[node](https://nodejs.org/) web page:

```
var http = require('http');
    http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');
```

which works great, but try to print something Cyrillic, like this:

```
var http = require('http');
    http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end('Здравей Свят\n');
}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');
```

You will get only badly decoded characters. I tried all kind of combinations with setting headers with different content-types, content-lengths, employing node-iconv module and other things, but i find my self going in circles.

Basically, I have mean-based web app and I **just** want to display Cyrillic text from my html/jade files to client browser. A few days digging already, with no results. I am sure if someone can tell what should be done in order for the above code to work, I will adapt it to my app (as I already am pretty sure, the issue is coming from some lower level, rather than from express midlewares etc..)

As far as I understood correctly - It seems to be an old issue originating somewhere in the way how javascript/v8 deal with utf-8. I saw plenty of other posts complaining about similar problems, but since I have tried to adapt each of them with no luck, I guess I will take the risk to post a duplicate question and have my chances...

some of the other posts/threads I visited:

[Encoding error with node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21627106/encoding-error-with-node-js)

[node.js Nerve framework unicode response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3807576/node-js-nerve-framework-unicode-response)

[Dealing with the Cyrillic encoding in Node.Js / Express App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22440642/dealing-with-the-cyrillic-encoding-in-node-js-express-app)

http://dougal.gunters.org/blog/2012/03/14/dealing-with-utf-in-node-js/

[Node.js public static folder to serve js with utf-8 charset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14095347/node-js-public-static-folder-to-serve-js-with-utf-8-charset)

[Why can't I write Chinese characters in nodejs HTTP response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10470426/why-cant-i-write-chinese-characters-in-nodejs-http-response)

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: try setting the encoding explicitly `res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain; charset=utf-8'});`

Comment: Also, ensure your source file in UTF-8 encoded: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10125141/what-encoding-is-expected-for-node-js-source-code

Comment: Alastair's comment solved my problem and fixed my headache :) I am using WebStorm IDE and did not recall at all to check its own file encoding... Once i tried the node js example in notepad++, it worked directly. Even without the need for manually setting the charset. Thanks Alastair!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alastair's comment solved my problem and fixed my headache :)

I am using WebStorm IDE and did not recall at all to check its own file encoding... Once i tried the node js example in notepad++, it worked directly. Even without the need for manually setting the charset.

It turned out that it is not needed to set manually the encoding via

```
      res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain; charset=utf-8'});
```

So if anyone come to a similar problem I had - first verify the encoding of your source files!